# How to create a user group for network resource access?

Tags: network-shares, windows-networking, user-groups

Ours is a windows network. There are some systems with Windows 7 and some with Windows XP. Mine is a Windows 7 system. I would like to create a user group so that I can grant it permission to access shared folders.

- In the sharing dialogue (Right click -> Properties -> Sharing -> Advanced sharing) I can see option to select users or groups. ("Select users, computers, service accounts, or groups" dialogue -> `Find now` displays a list of computers and groups to select. )
- Also, I can specify the types of objects I want to look for -> options contains Object types -> users, groups etc.

But there is no option to create a group.

Do I need to create from Control Panel -> Network and Internet ? 
I [read about creating a homegroup](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/help/homegroup-from-start-to-finish) but it does not look like what I want -

> If your computer belongs to a domain,
>   you can join a homegroup but you can't
>   create one. You can access files and
>   resources on other homegroup
>   computers, but you can't share your
>   own files and resources with the
>   homegroup.

How do I do this? Just want to create a group so as to share files among teammates. Why are simple things done so complex?

Comment: What versions of Windows are you using specifically, the Home or Pro versions? And, just to clarify, you are in workgroup, not Microsoft domain?

Comment: @KCotreau - all are Professional versions - both Windows 7 and XP

Comment: @KCotreau - As seen in the network section of a Win XP system in the network, all our systems can be seen going to Entire Network -> Microsoft windows network -> <Our company's Network>. So all are not inside Workgroup.

Answer (score 1):

You can create user groups from:

- Local User Manager:

  ```
  lusrmgr.msc
  ```
- command-line:

  ```
  net localgroup Friends /add

  net user Joe Friends /add
  ```

Comment: I created a new group using lusrmgr.msc, added some users. But then while trying to share a folder, don't see that group in the options. If I open lusrmgr.msc again, I can see the group I have added. Any kind of restart of something is needed? Thanks btw

Comment: Don't see that group while inside advanced sharing options... ("Select users, computers, service accounts, or groups" dialogue -> Find now

Answer (score 0):

There is only 2 way of adding group or user (as far as I know). With remote powershell to the AD, or directly on the AD!

You can't create group unless you contact your AD with powershell or RDP.

It's bothersome, but it'll keep user to do crap on the ad!

Connect on your AD, create the group you want, add user in this group, and add this group to your share NTFS permissions.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

OK, now that I have those clarifications, I can give you an answer.

First, you really do not want to use local users for this otherwise you would need to keep the passwords sychronized on both their account and the account you create for them on your computer. You want to use domain users.

You would need to add all the domain users to your local group. You will go into `Control Panel>Administrative Tools>Computer Management>Local Users and Groups` and add your new group (right-click, "New group"). You will add members by double-clicking the group and then clicking "add". Click the "Location" button and make sure your domain is where you are picking users from. Click the "Advanced" button and then "Find now". Select your users.

Comment: looks like I have already followed the steps which you have mentioned, (through lusrmgr.msc as answered by @grawity). But the problem is I am not getting the group created by me when I actually attempt to share a folder (in its "Advanced" -> "Find now"). I have checked again that I have selected only users from my domain, while inside the "Locations" option.

Comment: Add some scren shots to your post. Not sure what you are doing, or not doing.